# how to configure nlmer/nmle for polynomial logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, polynomial

I previously modeled my data with `glmer` and it is OK:

```
model = glmer(optionval ~ ot1  +section:(ot1 ) + 
  (ot1-1|participant.id), data=current_data, family=binomial, 
   control = glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap", 
   calc.derivs = FALSE))
```

Now I am told that we may need a `nonlinear` model, so I am trying to transform the model into nonlinear ones.

I am new to `nlmer` and `nmle` packages, and the modelling functions seem to be very different from `glmer` kind, e.g. `selfStart` functions(SSlogis) along with the "`start`" parameter in the function. Current attempt may be nonsense:

```
 model = nlmer(optionval ~ SSlogis(ot1, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ 
         ot1+section:(ot1) +(ot1)|participant.id,
          data=current_data, start = getInitial(optionval ~ 
         SSlogis(ot1, Asym, xmid, scal), data = 
           current_data), control =glmerControl(optimizer = 
           "nloptwrap", calc.derivs = FALSE))
```

It can run but produce the error message of:

```
 Error in eval_f(x, ...) : step factor reduced below 0.001  
   without reducing pwrss
```

I believe the model is not configured in the right way. Can anyone please suggest some ideas or a sample to use nlmer/nmle?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to do polynomial logistic regression or do you want to fit the logistic function? These are not the same at all.

Comment: @Roland Hi, I want to do polynomial logistic regression for my time course data, as you can see ot(orthogonal polynomial) in the formula.

Comment: Why are you not using the `poly` function in the formula? Polynomial regression is linear, no need for `nlmer`.

Comment: @Roland poly() has already applied before modelling, transforming "time" column into "ot"(1-3) in the dataframe so that I can directly index in the formula. I understand Polynomial regression is linear and current glmer is perfectly fine, but there is a need to change the formula into a nonlinear one, so I am preparing the nonlinear model function for that.